# How to set radio button checked based on condition in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-forms

How to set `checked` and `click` event for radio button.

Scenario:

- If it's **Service group** radio button 2 should be checked and disable first 
  button and block.
- If it's **Access group** both radio should behave normally and display div properly on click of each.

I tried something like this.

```
<label for="{{radio1.id}}" class="radio" (click)="radioSelected(radio1.label)">
    <input type="radio" id="{{radio1.id}}" name="optionsRadio41" value="{{radio1.value}}" required="" [disabled]="requestGroupName == 'SERVICE_GROUP'" [checked]="GroupName ==='ACCESS_GROUP'">
    <i class="skin"></i>
    <span>Within this solution</span>
</label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="{{radio2.id}}" class="radio" (click)="radioSelected(radio2.label)">
    <input type="radio" id="{{radio2.id}}" [checked]="GroupName ==='SERVICE_GROUP'" name="optionsRadio41" value="{{radio2.value}}" required="">
    <i class="skin"></i>
    <span>Copy to a different solution</span>
</label>
<div *ngIf="radioSelectedLabel=='Within this solution'">first block </div>
<div *ngIf="radioSelectedLabel=='Within this solution'">second block</div>
```

How can I achieve both conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working example, Please have a look at it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-tutorial-zaaf4q

if you want to toggle attribute you need to do `[attr.checked]` instead of `[checked]`, but in your case it will not work because you need to remove or add attibute.

I have created the directive which is taking the object of atributes like `{attributeName: boolean,attributeName2: boolean, ... }` and will add or remove the attribute depends of the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

this works with me

```
[checked]="item.HeadOpinion==managerOpinion.Approved"
```